# How to set zookeeper chroot path when connect to kafka with Golang?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

With Kafka Tool, my configuration is like:

```
Zookeeper Host:192.168.60.97
Zookeeper Port:2181
chroot path: /kafka1
```

But when I try this

```
consumer, err = sarama.NewConsumer([]string{"192.168.60.97:2181:/kafka1"}, nil)
```

I always got

```
kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify a Zookeeper chroot, it is used by Kafka to store all its metadata in Zookeeper.

The Kafka Consumer does not connect to Zookeeper, it only connects to Kafka. You need to specify the Kafka bootstrap servers in your consumer configuration.

In your example, it looks like you are passing the Zookeeper URL to your consumer, hence why it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for you response. But I didn't find any function to specify the kafka bootsrap servers in the sarama.Config

Comment: Keep your code but instead of passing `192.168.60.97:2181:/kafka1` to the Consumer, give it the Kafka bootstrap servers. For example, if Kafka is on `192.168.60.97:9092`, use `sarama.NewConsumer([]string{"192.168.60.97:9092"}, nil)`